# SMS group text alerts

Tags: sms

I'd like to be able to send out occasional group text alerts via SMS blasts to a small set of people.  I'd rather not use a standard group text message because I want everyone's individual number to be private.  I don't want people to respond and bother everyone else on the list, so it seems like a tool that could send out several individual messages would be the right way to accomplish this need.

What options, if any, are available to accomplish this?

Comment: If you want recommendations for a specific app, you better ask at our sister site for software recommendations (as those are off-topic here). I'm not aware that's possible with what "stock Android" ships with. Hint: Take a look at [Wishy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=marco.wishy), which seems to meet your requirements. But asking for other means (as you've just done) is of course fine here :)

Answer (score 0):

The Google Messages app can do most of other than process unsubscribes. Just go to settings, advanced, group messaging:

[image]
<sup>(click image for larger variant)</sup>